# Find image dimensions without importing the full image?

Tags: image, files-and-directories, metadata

Is there a way to find the `ImageDimensions` of an image file without `Import`'ing each one? The reason being that I have a directory with millions of JPEGs and it's really slow to Import each one separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation [says how to do this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JPEG.html).

```
Import["image.jpg", "ImageSize"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.052691, {2048, 1366}}`

Comment: Nice, I totally missed that!